# Preserve 'read' permission using 'tar' and 'copy' commands

Tags: permissions, batch-file, cygwin, tar

I have 2 servers in different domains. I use 3rd server to run batch script. All servers have cygwin installed hence I use Linux shell commands as well. All server could talk to each other. The goal: copy a folder from source server to destination. Since it has a million files in it I am going to use tar utility. I am able to run the script on 3rd server and create a tar file from source folder, copy it to destination folder and untag it.
It works fine ... except folders and files on destination server can't be opened because I have an error: access denied. I see that files don't have 'read' permission. If I run chmod a+r * on files it works fine.
Note: I use the same user on all servers.
How could I preserve 'read' access to the files?
I will attach my batch later:

```
SET SRC1=\\source-server\D$ 
 SET CMD1=pushd %SRC1% 
 SET SRC2=MyTar\ 
 SET SRC3=result.tar 
 SET CMD2=tar cfpz %SRC2%%SRC3% %SRC2% 
 SET DST1=\\destination-server\D$ 
 SET CMD3=copy %SRC2%%SRC3% %DST1% /y 
 SET CMD4=pushd %DST1% 
 SET CMD5=tar xfpz %SRC3% 

 %CMD1% 
 %CMD2% 
 %CMD3% 
 %CMD4% 
 %CMD5%
```

Comment: Have the the 3 users the same SID ? You can have it from `mkpasswd | grep your_user | awk 'BEGIN { FS=":"}; {print $5}'`

Comment: Well I checked that 2 servers i.e. the one where source files are located and  the one where I'm running the script has the same user with the same SID. But the user on destination-server i.e. where I open tar file is not listed in mkpasswd at all

Comment: I think that I have to add user to destination server since mkpasswd does not list it.
Could someone give a hint how to add the user in order mkpasswd list it? Thanks